# Streamer and reader cant' read folder and file in direcory

Tags: c#

In my c# windows form program i have a Treeview that should be populated with files and directories taken from a server via FtP. The problem is that i am able to take only the first level folders with this code:

```
    private void RecreateTree(string drive)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        treeView1.ImageList = Images;
        TreeNode node;
        dtId.Clear();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        string sqlNome = "SELECT DISTINCT Id, Descrizione FROM AmiantoAllegatiCartelle WHERE Livello = 1";
        Modulo.SqlDownloadData(Modulo.PathDBDati, sqlNome, ref da);
        da.Fill(dtId);
        foreach (DataRow r in dtId.Rows)
        {
            node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(r["Descrizione"].ToString(), r["Descrizione"].ToString(), 0, 0);
            string sottocartella = cartella + r["Descrizione"].ToString();
            AddChildren(sottocartella, ref node);
        }
    }
```

But when i try to get the Children of these directories, the property CanRead of the Streamer go to False.

Here is the code:

```
    private void AddChildren(string sPath, ref TreeNode n)
    {
        if (n.ToString().IndexOf(".") == -1)
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sPath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Modulo.UserNameFTP, Modulo.passwordFTP);
            WebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream streamer = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamer);
            string sottocartella;
            do
            {
                sottocartella = reader.ReadLine();
                if (sottocartella != null)
                {
                    if (sottocartella.Length > 2)
                    {
                        if (sottocartella.IndexOf(".") > -1)
                            n.Nodes.Add(sottocartella, sottocartella, 2, 2);
                        else
                            n.Nodes.Add(sottocartella, sottocartella, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            while (sottocartella != null);
            response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Can you help me? 
Thank you

EDIT, here is the full code of the treeview

```
    private void SetDrives()
    {
        RecreateTree(cartella);
    }

    private void RecreateTree(string drive)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        treeView1.ImageList = Images;
        TreeNode node;
        dtId.Clear();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        string sqlNome = "SELECT DISTINCT Id, Descrizione FROM AmiantoAllegatiCartelle WHERE Livello = 1";
        Modulo.SqlDownloadData(Modulo.PathDBDati, sqlNome, ref da);
        da.Fill(dtId);
        foreach (DataRow r in dtId.Rows)
        {
            node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(r["Descrizione"].ToString(), r["Descrizione"].ToString(), 0, 0);
            string sottocartella = cartella + r["Descrizione"].ToString();
            AddChildren(sottocartella, node);
        }
    }

    private void AddChildren(string sPath, TreeNode n)
    {
        if (n.ToString().IndexOf(".") == -1)
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sPath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Modulo.UserNameFTP, Modulo.passwordFTP);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream streamer = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamer);
            string sottocartella;
            do
            {
                sottocartella = reader.ReadLine();
                if (sottocartella != null)
                {
                    if (sottocartella.Length > 2)
                    {
                        if (sottocartella.IndexOf(".") > -1)
                            n.Nodes.Add(sottocartella, sottocartella, 2, 2);
                        else
                            n.Nodes.Add(sottocartella, sottocartella, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            while (sottocartella != null);
            response.Close();
        }
    }

    private void TreeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        foreach (TreeNode n in e.Node.Nodes)
        {
            node = n;
            n.Nodes.Clear();
            AddChildren(cartella + n.FullPath, node);
        }
        e.Node.ImageIndex = 1;
        e.Node.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
    }

    private void TreeView1_AfterCollapse(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Node.ImageIndex = 0;
        e.Node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
    }

    private void TreeView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // (TreeView1.SelectedNode.Name) restituisce il nome del nodo selezionato
        // (TreeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath) restituisce il percorso dal nodo principale
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.IndexOf(".") > -1)
        {
            string nomefile = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name;
            string percorso = cartella + treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.FullPath + "/";
            Modulo.ImportaFileAllegato(nomefile, percorso);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. You should not pass the `TreeNode node` by reference. That is not required. 2. You would like to get the files in the directory (call your AddChildren() method) in TreeView_OnBeforeExpand event handler, instead of loading all the tree view in one go. For the CanRead part, why don't you do `FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` ?  Please check the status code (.StatusCode) and the .ContentLength of the response

Comment: I removed the ref part so I don't pass the node by reference, the method RecreateTree is called in the Load of the form that contains the treeview, and I have also the method
private void TreeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
            foreach (TreeNode n in e.Node.Nodes)
            {
                node = n;
                n.Nodes.Clear();
                AddChildren(cartella + n.FullPath, node);
            }
            e.Node.ImageIndex = 1;
            e.Node.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
        }

Comment: The response has ContentLength = -1 and StatusCode = OpeningData

Comment: You should read about that openlngdata state, set FTP to text transfer mode, it is probably trying to open another connection for binary transfer currently

Comment: Please post your full implementation, not just parts of it

Comment: ok, question with full code. How i can set FTP to text trasfer mode? thanks for that

Comment: It is automatic I think, check this to see trace information, and also documentation says when you Close() the response stream, the StatusCode will have its final value (the actual error)

Comment: @OguzOzgul It's impossibile, i can't reach deeper files and folder... Timeout error also with readToEnd insted readLine